# Installing drivers in Windows 7 from CD executable or from Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I know 2 ways of installing drivers for devices, both from a CD, but in a different manner:

1. **Execute the CD**  that comes with the device and install the drivers through some menu in the CD.
2. Go to the **Device Manager**, right-click the device, select install driver and tell it to look into the CD for the driver.

I prefer *option 2* because the driver installation is not shown in the list of installed software, so this list is cleaner... However, *option 1* sometimes allows you to install some extra utilities, although I usually find these barely useful...

But, apart from that, is there any other difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often when running the standalone setup executable from a disc, you will have an executable that not just copies and load drivers, but installs utilities, applications and other bloatware into the program files directory.

Many prefer option 2 since often you can avoid the bloatware and load just the bare .dll files and .inf files. This is the miniamilist approach, and works well on some but not all devices.

Often these setup CDs will copy more than just drivers you need, it'll copy drivers for the entire family of products, whereas installing from the device manager will usually import only the core files you need.

A good example is the HP toolbox utility that used to get installed with desktop inkjet printers 15 some years ago. You didn't need it to print, all it did was monitor ink levels and give you pop up warnings about ink levels. This program wasn't needed, but got installed from the setup.exe that existed on the CD.

In some cases, you actually need the utilities, but in many cases you don't. It's just a matter of preference.

See Also: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000834.htm